# A grammar for the complement of language $L=\{a^{t+3}b^t:t \ge 0\}$

Tags: automata, formal-grammar

Assume that the  language $L=\{a^{t+3}b^t:t \ge 0\}$ is given.
Q1 : How can we write a grammar for the complement of this language?
Q2 : Assume that $L'=\{a^nb^m:n\ge0,m\gt n\}$ is given. Can you write a grammar for $L'\cap L$?

Note: I can easily write a grammar like this for the language $L$ itself.

```
S->aaaP
P->aPb
P->E
```

Also, I can easily write the grammar for $L'$:

```
S->PbX
X->bX
X->E
P->aPb
P->E
```

In these grammars, by E , i mean the empty string.
The first problem is the complementation and the second one is that i don't know how strings are made in the language $L' \cap L$ .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $L'$ and $L$ are sets, and their intersection is the usual intersection of sets: $L'\cap L$ is just the set of strings that are in both $L'$ and $L$; which strings are those?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I changed the question a little bit. Does that string exist ?

Comment: I saw the change; it makes the second problem even easier. Originally the intersection was just $L$; now, as I think you’re suggesting, it’s $\varnothing$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I agree with you :) But i have no idea about a good or maybe short grammar for the complement of $L$.

Comment: I’ll have to think about that; I agree that it’s not immediately clear. I think that I see a way to do it, but it’s a bit messy, and I’ve not checked all of the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Corrected** HINT: Everything matching the regular expression

$$b^*+ab^*+aab^*+aaaaa^*+(a+b)^*ba(a+b)^*\tag{1}$$

is in the complement of $L$, and it’s easy to write a grammar for this part of the complement. Every string in the rest of the complement begins with $aaa$, contains at least one $b$, and does not contain the string $ba$, so it must be $a^nb^m$ for some $n\ge 3$ and $m\ge 1$. You can handle this part of the complement by breaking it into two parts:

- strings of the form $a^{n+3}b^m$ such that $1\le m<n$, those that have too few $b$s; and
- strings that begin $a^{n+3}b^m$ such that $0\le n<m$, those that have too many $b$s.

Those in the first part must begin with at least $5$ $a$s; you can get them with

$$\begin{align*}
&S\to aaaaaFbX\\
&F\to aFb\mid A\\
&A\to aA\mid\epsilon\\
&X\to aY\mid a\mid\epsilon\\
&Y\to aY\mid bY\mid\epsilon
\end{align*}$$

See if you can work out a grammar for the other part and combine it with a grammar for the regular expression $(1)$ to get the desired grammar for the complement of $L$.

Comment: what about this string?  "abab"

Comment: @Arman: (I was offline yesterday). Oops: I meant to add appropriate clauses to the regular expression to cover such expressions. I’ll fix it in a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you :) i'll accept that

Comment: @Arman: You’re welcome. (The third case of my original version was supposed to cover the $(a+b)^*ba(a+b)^*$ case, but I slipped up and did it only for the strings that began with at least $5$ $a$s. It was only when I came to repair it that I realized that it was actually a regular sublanguage that could be taken care of right away.)